# Create database with variable name in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

This must be very simple but I can't figure it out, or maybe it is not possible.

I have the next function:

```
private static bool createDB(SqlConnection dbConn, string dbName)
{
    string sqlString = "CREATE DATABASE @dbname";
    using (dbConn)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, dbConn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbname", dbName);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            dbConn.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Se creo la DB");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se creo la DB");
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                //dbConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But apparently the @dbname is not getting the value, dbName does gets the name I want when I call it, but the exception says incorrect syntax near '@dbname'.

I'm new to C#, please be nice :) I got this from many other posts with prepared statements, but I couldn't find any with a CREATE DATABASE, but I'm assuming this should be very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't allow to do that. Database names and field names will not work this way.

```
string sqlString = "CREATE DATABASE " + dbname";
```

Only parameters are allow. Example

```
string sqlString = "update test set myField = @myVal"
```

you can then use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myVal", yourVar);
```

You also don't need to add @ in Parameters.AddWithValue as it's just implied already.

You always want to add parameters with Parameters.AddWithValue to avoid people from escaping and performing sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use SqlParameters for this, just add the **dbName** variable to your command text.

```
private static bool createDB(SqlConnection dbConn, string dbName)
{
    string sqlString = "CREATE DATABASE " + dbname;
    using (dbConn)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, dbConn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            dbConn.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Se creo la DB");
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se creo la DB");
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                //dbConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note I wouldn't put a messagebox (I assume this is test code) in a CRUD method like this not to mention this leaves the db connection open until the messagebox is acknowledged.

Comment: Sorry man, your answer didn't explain anything before, that's why I marked Tsukasa answer as the answer, and yes, my messageboxes are only for testing purpose. But I did marked it as useful, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you must "paramertize" the database name, then I'd suggest trying something like this...

```
string sqlString = string.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0}", dbName.Trim().Replace(" ",""));
```

It will also help guard against SQL injection, help not prevent, but at least you'd be ok with the [littlebobbytables](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png) exploits.

Comment: tough crowd... didn't even get a bump for the little bobby tables reference?

Comment: Lol, little bobby tables was awesome.